How to Compute Left Indentation for Numbered Paragraphs in OOXML (document.xml) from a DOCX File?
I'm working with a DOCX file and examining the document.xml (OOXML) file to determine the left indentation of paragraphs. Specifically, I'm trying to calculate the distance from the left margin to the first pixel of a numbered paragraph.
I've found this to be quite tricky, especially with numbered paragraphs. In some cases, the indentation equals indent, but this is not consistent. Sometimes it seems to be indent - hanging-indent.
I suspect there are other factors that influence the indentation calculation, as both MS Word and LibreOffice render the indentations correctly.
Can anyone explain the algorithm or rules used to compute the left indentation for numbered paragraphs in OOXML? Any insights or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.
(the data you see on the screenshot is edn format but it is directly obtained from the ooxml via Apache POI)


I'm adding more info / data, hopefully helping to understand my question.
Blow are the two images of the same document but with different paragraphs selected to reflect the ruler corresponding to each.

(good morning paragraph)

(xxxxxxxxx paragraph)

(the corresponding ooxml file)



public static double computeIndent(Indentation indentation) {
    double leftIndent = indentation.indLeftInTwip == -1 ? 0.0 : indentation.indLeftInTwip;
    double firstLineIndent = indentation.indFirstLineInTwip == -1 ? 0.0 : indentation.indFirstLineInTwip;
    double hangingIndent = indentation.indHangingInTwip == -1 ? 0.0 : indentation.indHangingInTwip;

    double computedIndent;

    if (indentation.indLeftInTwip != -1 && indentation.indHangingInTwip != -1) {
        computedIndent = leftIndent - hangingIndent;
    } else if (indentation.indLeftInTwip != -1 && indentation.indFirstLineInTwip != -1) {
        computedIndent = leftIndent + firstLineIndent;
    } else if (indentation.indLeftInTwip != -1) {
        computedIndent = leftIndent;
    } else if (indentation.indFirstLineInTwip != -1) {
        computedIndent = firstLineIndent;
    } else {
        computedIndent = 0.0;
    }

    return computedIndent;
}


The problem is that, even if the file system Office Open XML was published now, the application software of Microsoft Office still is closed source. Thus nobody knows how Microsoft Word really processes the Office Open XML.
According to the ECMA-376 Office Open XML file formats specification it should be like this:

17.3.1.12 ind (Paragraph Indentation)
This element specifies the set of indentation properties applied to
the current paragraph.
Indentation settings are overriden on an individual basis - if any
single attribute on this element is omitted on a given paragraph, its
value is determined by the setting previously set at any level of the
style hierarchy (i.e. that previous setting remains unchanged). If any
single attribute on this element is never specified in the style
hierarchy, then no indentation of that indentation type is applied to
the paragraph.

This "style hierarchy" is pecified like so:

17.7.2 Style Hierarchy
This process can be described as follows:

First, the document defaults are applied to all runs and paragraphs    in the document.
Next, the table style properties are applied to each table in the    document, following the conditional formatting inclusions and
exclusions specified per table.
Next, numbered item and paragraph properties are applied to each    paragraph formatted with a numbering style.
Next, paragraph and run properties are applied to each paragraph as    defined by the paragraph style.
Next, run properties are applied to each run with a specific    character style applied.
Finally, we apply direct formatting (paragraph or run properties    not from styles). If this direct formatting includes numbering, that
numbering + the associated paragraph properties are applied.


If, and only if, Microsoft processes the Office Open XML exactly as specified, then following should be true:
The paragraph indentation is part of paragraph properties. These can be stored in document.xml directly in paragraph XML - direct formatting. If so, then all that indentation settings apply, except the not set there.
Run properties cannot set indentation settings.
For not set indentation settings, paragraph properties of abstract numberings linked to the paragraph apply. The abstract numbering is linked to the paragraph by a num-ID and a num-indentation-level. Both links to an abstact numbering in numbering.xml and a special num-indentation-level. The num-indentation-level may have paragraph properties containing indentation settings.
For further not set indentation settings, paragraph properties of a style linked to the paragraph apply. A style is linked to the paragraph by a style-ID. This links to a style in styles.xml which may have paragraph properties containing indentation settings.
Not clear whether table style properties may have paragraph properties  too. But I don't think so as table cells contain default paragraphs.
The document defaults may set up paragraph properties but I've never seen that document defaults set up indentations. But nevertheless we test it.
So to get the applying paragraph indentation using Apache POI:

At first test indentation via paragraph properties of
XWPFParagraph.
At second test indentation via paragraph properties of
XWPFAbstractNum and update indentation settings which not got set
in first step.
At third test indentation via paragraph properties of XWPFStyle
and update indentation settings which not got set in first and
second step.
At fourth test indentation via default paragraph properties of
XWPFDefaultParagraphStyle and update indentation settings which
not got set in first, second and third step.

For me that gets correct indentation for all my test cases. But who knows... ;-). See first paragraph in this answer.
Complete code to test:
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WordGetParagraphIndentation {
    
 static Indentation getParagraphIndentationFromNumIlvl(XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum, BigInteger numIlvl, Indentation indentation) {
  boolean found = false;
  for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTLvl lvl : abstractNum.getCTAbstractNum().getLvlList()) {
   if (numIlvl == null) { // no Ilvl, take the first lvl
    found = true;
   } else if (numIlvl != null && lvl.getIlvl().equals(numIlvl)) { // if Ilvl find the correct lvl
    found = true;  
   }
   if (found) {
    if (lvl.getPPr() != null) {
     if (lvl.getPPr().getInd() != null) {
      if (lvl.getPPr().getInd().getLeft() != null) {
       if(indentation.indLeftInTwip == -1) indentation.indLeftInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(lvl.getPPr().getInd().getLeft()));
      }
      if (lvl.getPPr().getInd().getHanging() != null) {
       if(indentation.indHangingInTwip == -1) indentation.indHangingInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(lvl.getPPr().getInd().getHanging()));
      }
      if (lvl.getPPr().getInd().getFirstLine() != null) {
       if(indentation.indFirstLineInTwip == -1) indentation.indFirstLineInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(lvl.getPPr().getInd().getFirstLine()));
      }
      if (lvl.getPPr().getInd().getRight() != null) {
       if(indentation.indRightInTwip == -1) indentation.indRightInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(lvl.getPPr().getInd().getRight()));
      }
     }
    }
    break;  
   }
  }
  return indentation; 
 }
 
 static Indentation getParagraphIndentationFromStyle(XWPFStyle style, Indentation indentation) {
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTStyle ctStyle = style.getCTStyle();
  if (ctStyle.getPPr() != null) {
   if (ctStyle.getPPr().getInd() != null) {
    if (ctStyle.getPPr().getInd().getLeft() != null) {
     if(indentation.indLeftInTwip == -1) indentation.indLeftInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ctStyle.getPPr().getInd().getLeft()));
    }
    if (ctStyle.getPPr().getInd().getHanging() != null) {
     if(indentation.indHangingInTwip == -1) indentation.indHangingInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ctStyle.getPPr().getInd().getHanging()));
    }
    if (ctStyle.getPPr().getInd().getFirstLine() != null) {
     if(indentation.indFirstLineInTwip == -1) indentation.indFirstLineInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ctStyle.getPPr().getInd().getFirstLine()));
    }
    if (ctStyle.getPPr().getInd().getRight() != null) {
     if(indentation.indRightInTwip == -1) indentation.indRightInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ctStyle.getPPr().getInd().getRight()));
    }
   }
  }
  return indentation; 
 }
 
 static Indentation getParagraphIndentationFromDefaultParagraphStyle(XWPFDefaultParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle, Indentation indentation) {
  try {
   java.lang.reflect.Method getPPr = XWPFDefaultParagraphStyle.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPPr");
   getPPr.setAccessible(true);
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPrGeneral ctPPrGeneral = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPrGeneral)getPPr.invoke(defaultParagraphStyle);
   if (ctPPrGeneral != null) {
    if (ctPPrGeneral.getInd() != null) {
     if (ctPPrGeneral.getInd().getLeft() != null) {
      if(indentation.indLeftInTwip == -1) indentation.indLeftInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ctPPrGeneral.getInd().getLeft()));
     }
     if (ctPPrGeneral.getInd().getHanging() != null) {
      if(indentation.indHangingInTwip == -1) indentation.indHangingInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ctPPrGeneral.getInd().getHanging()));
     }
     if (ctPPrGeneral.getInd().getFirstLine() != null) {
      if(indentation.indFirstLineInTwip == -1) indentation.indFirstLineInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ctPPrGeneral.getInd().getFirstLine()));
     }
     if (ctPPrGeneral.getInd().getRight() != null) {
      if(indentation.indRightInTwip == -1) indentation.indRightInTwip = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ctPPrGeneral.getInd().getRight()));
     }
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return indentation; 
 }
               
 static Indentation getParagraphIndentation(XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
  Indentation indentation = new Indentation();

  // first test indentation via paragraph properties of XWPFParagraph
  indentation.indLeftInTwip = paragraph.getIndentationLeft();
  indentation.indHangingInTwip = paragraph.getIndentationHanging();
  indentation.indFirstLineInTwip = paragraph.getIndentationFirstLine();
  indentation.indRightInTwip = paragraph.getIndentationRight();
 
  // second test indentation via paragraph properties of XWPFAbstractNum 
  if (indentation.notAll()) {
   BigInteger numID = paragraph.getNumID();
   BigInteger numIlvl = paragraph.getNumIlvl();
   if (numID != null) {
    XWPFNumbering numbering = paragraph.getDocument().getNumbering();
    if (numbering != null) {
     XWPFNum num = numbering.getNum(numID);
     if (num != null) {
      BigInteger abstractNumID = num.getCTNum().getAbstractNumId().getVal();
      XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = numbering.getAbstractNum(abstractNumID);
      indentation = getParagraphIndentationFromNumIlvl(abstractNum, numIlvl, indentation);
     }
    }
   }   
  }

  // third test indentation via paragraph properties of XWPFStyle 
  if (indentation.notAll()) {
   String styleID = paragraph.getStyleID();
   if (styleID != null) {
    XWPFStyles styles = paragraph.getDocument().getStyles();
    if (styles != null) {
     XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyle(styleID);
     if (style != null) {
      indentation = getParagraphIndentationFromStyle(style, indentation);
     }
    }   
   }
  }
  
  // fourth test indentatio via paragraph properties of  XWPFDefaultParagraphStyle
  if (indentation.notAll()) {
   XWPFStyles styles = paragraph.getDocument().getStyles();
   if (styles != null) {
    XWPFDefaultParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle = styles.getDefaultParagraphStyle();
    indentation = getParagraphIndentationFromDefaultParagraphStyle(defaultParagraphStyle, indentation);    
   }
  }
 
  // fifth ???
  
  return indentation;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) { 
  try ( XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.docx")); ) {
  
   for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
    Indentation indentation = getParagraphIndentation(paragraph);
    System.out.println(paragraph.getText());
    System.out.println(indentation);
   }
   
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 
 static class Indentation {
  int indLeftInTwip;
  int indHangingInTwip;
  int indFirstLineInTwip;
  int indRightInTwip;
  Indentation() {
   this.indLeftInTwip = -1;
   this.indHangingInTwip = -1;
   this.indFirstLineInTwip = -1;
   this.indRightInTwip = -1;
  }
  boolean notAll() {
   return this.indLeftInTwip == -1 || this.indHangingInTwip == -1 || this.indFirstLineInTwip == -1 || this.indRightInTwip == -1;
  }
  public String toString() {
   this.indLeftInTwip = (this.indLeftInTwip == -1)?0:this.indLeftInTwip;
   this.indHangingInTwip = (this.indHangingInTwip == -1)?0:this.indHangingInTwip;
   this.indFirstLineInTwip = (this.indFirstLineInTwip == -1)?0:this.indFirstLineInTwip;
   this.indRightInTwip = (this.indRightInTwip == -1)?0:this.indRightInTwip;
   return "left:=" + this.indLeftInTwip/1440f*25.4 + "mm" + "\n"
        + "hanging:=" + this.indHangingInTwip/1440f*25.4 + "mm" + "\n"
        + "first line:=" + this.indFirstLineInTwip/1440f*25.4 + "mm" + "\n"
        + "right:=" + this.indRightInTwip/1440f*25.4 + "mm" ;
  }
 }
}


I think we are arriving at the solution.
But, since my paragraph has:
<w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:numPr>
      <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
      <w:numId w:val="10"/>
    </w:numPr>
    <w:tabs>
      <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="2960"/>
    </w:tabs>
    <w:spacing w:before="241"/>
    <w:ind w:right="108"/>
  </w:pPr>

it results in:
:para-left-in-twip  -1
:para-hanging-in-twip -1
:para-first-line-in-twip -1
:para-right-in-twip 108

and since not all values are -1 it doesn't try to resolve left indentation form the numbering or style.

What would be the best logic for partial -1 values? What the OOXML spec says about it? If for example hanging indent is positive and the left indent is -1 , should I ignore both and try to resolve them with numbering/style or I should accept any positive numbers and only resole the missing ones with subsequent strategies?

@Lambder: You are correct. I've updated my answer and code. Hope that fits now ;-).

I gave you code a go (had to translate to Clojure as this is the language I'm working with) and I see the geometry is retrieved correctly. Now I'd like to have the final ask for you to check if the code at the bottom of the question (just added) the info correctly in determination of the most left pixel of a given paragraph. Thanks a ton Axel.

@Lambder: Looks correct. The firstLine and hanging attributes are mutually exclusive, if both are specified, then
the firstLine value is ignored. One addition needed in my opinion. It is possible to have hanging set as the only attribute. Thus there should also be ... else if (indentation.indHangingInTwip != -1) { computedIndent = 0d - hangingIndent; ...

The edn format aside Office Open XML format stores XML like this for indentations:
...
<w:ind w:left="1440" w:hanging="480"/>
...

The values are in Twip (twentieth of an inch point), 1440 Twip = 1 inch. There are 72 inch points per inch and that get multiplied by 20 to avoid floating point in XML. Thus there are 1440 Twip per inch.
The meaning of left and hanging are as follows: The left determines the left indentation from left page border  to the text. The hanging determines how much the first text line hangs before the rest of the text lines, if any, or how much numbering symbols hang before the text.
Following picture shows this:

So above XML means: Left indentation of 1 inch and hanging indentation of 1/3 inch.
Text indentation can be set in paragraph settings directly via Paragraph.setIndentFromLeft and Paragraph.setIndentationHanging. For numberings it also can be set via paragraph properties in numbering level.
Complete example showing both:
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTLvl;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STNumberFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordListIndentation {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  ArrayList<String> documentList = new ArrayList<String>(
   Arrays.asList(
    new String[] {
     "One",
     "Two",
     "Three"
    }));

  // set numbering
  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
  //Next we set the AbstractNumId. This requires care.
  //Since we are in a new document we can start numbering from 0.
  //But if we have an existing document, we must determine the next free number first.
  cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

  //Bullet list
  CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
  cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.BULLET);
  cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("-");

  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();

  BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
  BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The list having defined gap between bullet point and text set by paragraph settings:");

  for (String string : documentList) {
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numID);
   // set font size by paragraph run properties - used for the bukllet sysmbol
   paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewRPr().addNewSz().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(48)); // half pt
   // set indents in Twips (twentieth of an inch point), 1440 Twips = 1 inch
   paragraph.setIndentFromLeft(1440); // indent from left 1440 Twips = 1 inch
   paragraph.setIndentationHanging(1440/3); // indentation hanging 1440/3 Twips = 1/3 inch
                                            // so bullet point hangs 1/3 inch before the text at indentation 2/3 inch from left
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText(string);
   run.setFontSize(24);
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  

  // the same but set by numbering settings
  cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
  cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  //Bullet list
  cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
  cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.BULLET);
  cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("-");
  // paragraph properties in numbering level providing indentation
  cTLvl.addNewPPr();
  cTLvl.getPPr().addNewInd();
  cTLvl.getPPr().getInd().setLeft(1440);
  cTLvl.getPPr().getInd().setHanging(1440/3);

  abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
  numbering = document.createNumbering();

  abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
  numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The list having defined gap between bullet point and text set by numbering settings:");

  for (String string : documentList) {
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numID);
   // set font size by paragraph run properties - used for the bukllet sysmbol
   paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewRPr().addNewSz().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(48)); // half pt
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText(string);
   run.setFontSize(24);
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordListIndentation.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}


Yes, I know that. My issue is that for the numbered paragraphs (and only for numbered) the numbering bit (number, bulled point etc) are somethings shifted left by the hanging-indent value , sometimes even when there is non-zero hanging-indent the numbering starts at the exact position as the indent alone suggest so subtracting hanging-indent from it would give incorrect value (too much to the left). I even saw a case where all the numberings from the same numbered list had the same xml values but MS Word rendered them at different indents.

@Lambder: "shifted left by the hanging-indent value ": No, that can never happen. But there is a tab between numbering symbol and following text. And if there is neither the hanging indentation big enough to stop tat tab nor a tab stop position in paragraph settings, then this tab takes up space in the default tab-stop-size.

I've added extra info to the question. On the screenshots we see the indentation of the paragraphs to be 27mm and 40mm , whereas their corresponding numberings are 15mm and 33m. From the document.xml I can't deduce the 15 and 33 values or can I?

@Lambder: "From the document.xml I can't deduce the 15 and 33 values or can I?": You can't. You need the corresponding numbering.xml too. From my answer: "Text indentation can be set in paragraph settings directly via Paragraph.setIndentFromLeft and Paragraph.setIndentationHanging. For numberings it also can be set via paragraph properties in numbering level."

I've added info on the numbering.xml
