Paragraph indent in code does not match visual indent in editor
I'm creating converter docx -> html (html must be compatible with TinyMCE).
Sometimes I notice "strange" paragraphs that clearly have indent in editor but all related variables in code are 0 (IndentationHanging, IndentationFirstLine, IndentationLeft etc.) and corresponding xml structure does not have any indents:
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Calibri" w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
            <w:b/>
            <w:bCs/>
            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Calibri" w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
            <w:b/>
            <w:bCs/>
            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>General Litigation Procedures:</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>

Ruler shows left indent is about 36pt and hanging indent 18pt:

It looks like paragraph gets indent from the previous paragraph, sometimes some default indent, sometimes NPOI does not recognize w:start attribute.
How can I get correct indent value in code?

There are multiple places to store indentations in Office Open XML for Word. They can be stored in document, in numbering, in styles and in default settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78720541/how-to-compute-left-indentation-for-numbered-paragraphs-in-ooxml-document-xml/78726145#78726145. In your case, probably the style named "ListParagraph" will have set the indentation.

@AxelRichter, I swear I checked styles before but now I see there is indent in style, thanks! I'll update code to see if it solves 100% of indentation issues.

@AxelRichter, yes, everything works now, thank you again.
